# Unclickable anchor tag

Tags: html, css, anchor

I use this html code

```
<div class="titleIn"> 
    <h2><a href="/link2">link2</a></h2>
</div>
```

and for some reason the `link2` is not clickable (no hand cursor)

The CSS is:

```
.titleIn {
    direction: rtl;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    margin-right: 0;
    margin-top: -10px;
    position: relative;
    text-align: right;
    z-index: -1;
}
```

Any idea?

Comment: Why do you use `z-index: -1;`?

Comment: Which browser are you using? I can click the link with FF3.6

Comment: @funktu: Really? That's odd, I can't.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I can't say I know ***why***, but I know what's causing it: Your `z-index: -1`. If you remove that, the problem goes away (at least, it does for me on Chrome, Firefox, and Opera; not on IE6 or IE7, though). Here's [a live copy of your example](http://jsbin.com/ofufi), and [an updated copy](http://jsbin.com/ofufi/2) with `z-index: 0` instead.

By giving it a `z-index` less than zero, you're putting it below the main flow content, and I guess the document isn't letting the event pass through it (just like any element with a non-transparent background setting).

IE seems to have a separate issue with the combination of `direction: rtl;` and `position: relative;`, but I think it *is* a separate issue. If I remove every style in `.titleIn` except `direction: rtl; position: relative;`, IE still breaks (the link is unclickable). If I remove either of those, IE starts working (but of course, your layout doesn't do what you want).

Comment: This sounds pretty clear to me... just remove the `z-index: -1;`, is what he's saying :)

Comment: Isn't it clear enough? The element has a `z-index` of -1. Remove this statement and it'll work.

Answer (score 4):

Unless you made the body's z-index <-1, you are essentially putting the link behind the entire body of the page, of course it's not click-able. (Elements such as body and headings will span the entire width that it is defined, thus invisibly blocking other elements that maybe visible, but not click-able)

If you used Firebug, it will illustrate that pretty well by highlighting the area of the tag.

Comment: on a related note, if you have defined z-index elsewhere, it may be that they are not working b/c the position property is not defined.

Answer (score 0):

Well, when I try this in IE, the link becomes active only after I remove `position: relative;` and `margin-top: -10px;`. Soooo, do you really need the position: relative? :)