# Anchor not working in div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

```
<style type="text/css">
.xyz {
    position: absolute;
    top: 100px;
    left: 140px;
    z-index: -1;
}

#container {
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
    opacity: .2;
}
</style>

<body>
    <div>
        <video id="container" autoplay loop muted>
            <source src="<%=request.getContextPath()%>/Files/images/sample.mp4" type="video/mp4">
        </video>

        <div class="xyz">
            <a href="<%=request.getContextPath() %>/Files/jsp/Home.jsp">
                <img src="<%=request.getContextPath() %>/Files/images/play.png" height="50" width="50"
                    onmouseover="this.src='<%=request.getContextPath()%>/Files/images/Koala.jpg'">
            </a>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

The anchor tag here is not working. 
The image play.png should change to Koala.jpg on mouse over and when clicked Home.jsp should be displayed. But the code is working without div. Using anchor in div neither image is gettig changed using mouseover nor linking to Home.jsp.

Comment: I think your anchor is below an element, making it unclickable because of `z-index: -1` - [possible duplicate](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4537789/unclickable-anchor-tag)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just remove `z-index` from the CSS . Changed code :

```
.xyz {
    position: absolute;
    top: 100px;
    left: 140px;
}
```